# Javascript Insert string at index of string ignoring html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

So my situation is I have a string that for example could be: 
`Testing new  message  with an image`
So at index 12 and index 21 of that string I would like to insert image tags.
So I need help finding a way to insert 2 image tags at that string by index.
The problem is if I just insert them both at the index they should be something like this would happen:

`Testing new <img src="<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/> message with an image`

So the problem is that it will insert the first string correctly, but then it will shift the index of the next img tag index, which will then try to put the next img tag in the previous one.

There will be a dynamic number of images that I will be trying to add to a string so I need a solutions that basically looks at the string without the html tags and inserts it at the correct index, but still returns the string with the html tags in it.

Thanks for looking!

EDIT:
What I have so far is:

```
String.prototype.splice = function(idx, rem, str) {
    return this.slice(0, idx) + str + this.slice(idx + Math.abs(rem));
};
function addMessage(username, message, emotes, hexColor) {
    var htmlString = '<p style="color:' + hexColor + ';display:inline;">' + username + '</p>';
  addEmotesToString(emotes, message, function(newString) {
    var messageDiv = $('#chatMessages');
    var html = messageDiv.html();
  html += '<br>' + htmlString;
    html += '<p style="color:white;display:inline;">: ' + newString + '</p>';
    messageDiv.html(html);
  });
}

function addEmotesToString(emotes, string, callback) {
  var newString = string;
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < emotes.length; i++) {\
    newString.splice(emotes[i].index, 0, '<img src="' + emotes[i].url + '"/>';
    counter++;
    if (counter == emotes.length) {
      callback(newString);
    }
  }
}

function test() {
    var username = "newUser";
  var message = "Testing test  test  test";
  var hexColor = "#C3FF1F";
  var emotes = [{url: "imageurl", index: 13}, {url: "imageurl", index: 19}];
  addMessage(username, message, emotes, hexColor);
}
```

Comment: any code that you written?

Comment: I will add now.

Comment: And why you dont use DOM objects?

Comment: Can you just insert the last one first?

Comment: Updated with current code, so you can see what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you want to add some content in for example the center of the string. In this case you shoud get leftSide and rightSide of your string with substring method. Then you can concat leftSide with your content and rightSide. I hope this will help you.

Comment: I updated the post with my current code, hopefully it makes it more clear. I have a string that I want to insert a dynamic number of <img> tags at specific indexes in the string. But those indexes change when I add an <img> tag therefor I need to insert at an index that does not take any html tags into consideration.

Comment: I want to insert a string into another string at an index, the only problem is, I want to insert multiple strings into another string. The problem is each string is different and I dont know what it will be. They have to go in at a specific index in the string but when i add the first one, the index of the second, third, and so on change because there is more string which offsets the index. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can use variable offset. var offset = 0; When you add a string write offset += string.length. newString.splice(emotes[i].index, 0, '<img src="' + emotes[i].url + '"/>' Here write emotes[j].index + offset. Maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: Define variable offset in the start of your function

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to sort you emotes by index and insert them starting with the largest index. If you start at the right side of the string, you won't impact the index of the next inserts.

```
function addMessage(message, emotes) {
  emotes.sort(function(a, b){ // sort by index, greatest first
    return b.index - a.index
  })
  emotes.forEach(function(e) {
    message = message.slice(0, e.index) + e.url + message.slice(e.index) 
  })
  return message
}

function test() {
  var message = "0123456789";
  var emotes = [{url: "one", index: 3}, {url: "two", index: 9}];
  return addMessage(message, emotes);
}
console.log(test())
// => 012one345678two9
```